# I am new to Ubuntu, I have added mount points, but I dont know how to remove them

Tags: 20.04, mountpoint

I have been using  mount points for some of my drives, but, I have changed my available drives, and I I don't know how to list my current mount pints, to remove the UN-needed ones, or clear list and start fresh

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and include which version of Ubuntu you are using. Add the exact commands you used for creating these mount points. If you edited any files such as `/etc/fstab` add the contents of those files. Copy and paste them in your question. Add the list of drives you have installed, their partition information also.